# Align letter with line below in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, business-cards

I am trying to make a business card and want to perfectly align the beginning of a path (line in this case) with a letter. However, due to spacing added *before* the letter, the alignment does not seem perfect. The alignment is done (as should be) on the node, but I want to remove the small amount of spacing before the first (capital) letter.

I also made an attempt using `\underline`, without success.

MWE (I use XeLaTeX):

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
% preferred method
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},framed]
\draw[anchor=west] (0,0) node[align=left] (name)  {\Huge Here}; 
\draw[line width=0.03cm] ($(name.south west)+(0,-0.03in)$) -- ($(name.south west)+(1in,-0.03in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

% attempt with underline
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},framed]
\draw[anchor=west] (0,0) node[align=left] (name)   {\Huge\underline{Here}}; 
\draw[line width=0.03cm] ($(name.south west)+(0,-0.03in)$) --  ($(name.south west)+(1in,-0.03in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF output]

(XeLaTeX is not really required for this MWE, I know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XeTeX knows the side bearings, if OpenType(/TrueType) fonts are used (PFB fonts do not work):

```
\XeTeXglyphbounds1\XeTeXglyphindex"H"
```

Applied to the "preferred method" of the question:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}% OpenType of Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
% preferred method
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
  framed,
]
  \draw[anchor=west] (0,0) node[align=left] (name) {%
    \Huge Here%
    \xdef\LeftSideBearingH{\the\XeTeXglyphbounds1\XeTeXglyphindex"H" }%
    \typeout{* Left side bearing of H: \LeftSideBearingH}%
  };
  \draw[line width=0.03cm]
    ($(name.south west)+(\LeftSideBearingH, -0.03in)$) -- ++(1in, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The reported value:

```
* Left side bearing of H: 1.26888pt
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[border=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
% preferred method
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    here/.style = {font=\Huge,
                   inner xsep=-1.2pt,% <-- here is the trick
                   inner ysep=0.03in, outer sep=0pt},
    framed          ]
\node[here] (name)  {Here};
\draw[line width=0.03cm] (name.south west) -- ($(name.south west)+(1in,0in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or consider *percusse* comment, just move line for `1.2pt` to the right (result is the same as before):

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[border=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
% preferred method
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    here/.style = {font=\Huge,
                   inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=0.03in, outer sep=0pt},
    framed          ]
\node[here] (name)  {Here};
\draw[line width=0.03cm] ([xshift=1.2pt] name.south west) -- ([xshift=1in] name.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: negative sep spaces are not recommended

Comment: @percusse, it is really not good practice.  I add to my answer an alternative with shifting line to the right.